# How to upload new versions of an image with the same access path?

Tags: media, files

We have two sites, one is a static HTML site. Another is an Drupal site. For example:

- www.my-html.com
- www.my-drupal.com

On the my-html.com site, we have a dynamic image banner, links to a JPEG on the my-drupal.com site, which can be managed by the user using Drupal CMS, i.e.:

```
http://www.my-drupal.com/sites/default/files/my-html_banner.png
```

The users can upload new versions of the `my-html_banner.png` from time to time. Hopefully, when a new version of the image is uploaded on `my-drupal.com`, it will be refreshed on `my-html.com`.

However, the newer versions of the .png will end up with different filenames in `sites/default/files`, i.e.:

```
my-html_banner.png
my-html_banner_0.png
my-html_banner_1.png
...
```

Is there a way to use a fix path to refer to the latest version of a uploaded image? Or is it possible to config Drupal to replace existing image if the uploaded image name is identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Upload File Replace](https://drupal.org/project/upload_replace) module, This module solves that problem by swapping the names of the older and newer file so that the newly uploaded file will retain its original name.

> This is a small utility module that automatically stops Drupal from
>   renaming new files upload via filefield CCK. When 2 files with the
>   same name exist, the older files will be renamed.